# Deleting empty files in tar.gz file in bash

Tags: bash, powershell, shell, tar.gz

i have a tar.gz file and it contains .yang files along with some empty .yang files.
so i want to go into the tar.gz file and delete only those empty files
Currently i am using:

```
for f in *.tar.gz
 do
    echo "Processing file $f"
    gzip -d "$f"
    find $PWD -size  0 -print -delete
    gzip -9 "${f%.*}"
    echo "******************************************"
done
```

but this is not working maybe because currently, i m not in a directory instead inside the tar.gz file.

any other way to do this?

Comment: Why tag two very different shells? Bash is usually on Linux, and Powershell is usually on Windows.

Comment: You never go **inside** the tar file. For manipulating the content of a tar file, unzip it, and use `tar --delete` to remove things from your archive. When you are done, zip it again. See _man tar_.  And, please remove the _powershell_ tag from your question.

Comment: And, just being curious: What is the `gzip -9` supposed to do?

Comment: @user1934428 `gzip -9` compresses with the highest compression level. In this case it re-gzip the tarball. If the `find` command was doing what the OP want, all this would probably work. So the main issue is with this `find` command that does not suppress the empty files from the tarball.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet : Thanks for the explanation. BTW, I don't see a point in the `find` command anyway. After unzipping, we are left with a single _tar-ball_. The files in the archive are never extracted. The search for empty files should IMO done inside the tar. If we have GNU tar, this could perhaps be done using `--to-command`, which sets the environment variables `TAR_REALNAME` and `TAR_SIZE`....

Comment: @user1934428 For in-place tarball edition we need the GNU tar `--delete` option and we need to first find the names of the files to delete. Other options consist in unpacking, deleting and re-packing but there are several potential issues with this. See my answer for a detailed explanation of 3 solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Your `find` command doesn't do anything useful to your tarballs because it searches and deletes in the current directory, not inside the tarballs.

So we need to first unpack the tarball (`tar -xf`), delete the empty files (`find`), and repack (`tar -czf`). As a safety measure we will work in temporary directories (`mktemp -d`) and create new tarballs (`*.tar.gz.new`) instead of overwriting the old ones. As you want to delete only `yang` empty files, we will also use some more find options. The following is for GNU tar, adapt to your own tar version (or install GNU tar). Before using it read what comes next, just in case...

```sh
for f in *.tar.gz; do
    echo "Processing file $f"
    d="$(mktemp -d)"
    tar -xf "$f" -C "$d"
    find "$d" -type f -name '*.yang' -size 0 -print -delete
    tar -C "$d" -czf "$f.new" .
    rm -rf "$d"
    echo "******************************************"
done
```

But what you want is more complex than it seems because your tarballs could contain files with meta-data (owner, permissions...) that you are not allowed to use. If you run what precedes as a regular user, tar will silently change the ownership and permissions of such files and directories. When re-packing they will thus have modified meta-data. If it is a problem and you absolutely want to preserve the meta-data there are basically two options:

1. Pretend you are root with `fakeroot` or an equivalent.
2. Delete the files inside the tarballs without unpacking.

To use `fakeroot` just run the above bash script inside a `fakeroot` environment:

```sh
$ fakeroot
# for f in *.tar.gz; do
# ...
# done
# exit
```

The second solution (in-place tarball edition) uses GNU tar and GNU awk:

```sh
for f in *.tar.gz; do
    echo "Processing file $f"
    t="${f%.*}"
    gzip -cd "$f" > "$t"
    tar -tvf "$t" | awk -vORS=$"\0" '/^-.*\.yang$/ && $3==0 {
      match($0,/(\S+\s+){4}\S+\s/); print substr($0,RLENGTH+1)}' |
      xargs -0 -n1 tar -f "$t" --delete
    gzip -c9 "$t" > "$f.new"
    echo "******************************************"
done
```

Explanations:

We use the GNU tar `--delete` option to delete files directly inside the tarball, without unpacking it, which is probably more elegant (even if it is also probably slower than a `fakeroot`-based solution).

Let's first find all empty files in the tarball:

```sh
$ tar -tvf foo.tar
drwx------ john/users        0 2021-10-18 14:26 ./
drwx------ john/users        0 2021-10-18 16:34 ./
-rw------- john/users        0 2021-10-18 16:34 ./nonyang
drwx------ john/users        0 2021-10-18 15:22 ./foo.yang/
-rw------- john/users        0 2021-10-18 16:01 ./empty.yang
-rw------- john/users        7 2021-10-18 15:22 ./nonempty.yang
-rw------- john/users        0 2021-10-18 16:01 ./filename with spaces.yang
```

As you can see the size is in third column. Directory names have a leading `d` and a trailing `/`. Symbolic links have a leading `l`. So by keeping only lines starting with `-` and ending with `.yang` we eliminate them. GNU awk can do this twofold filtering:

```sh
$ tar -tvf foo.tar | awk '/^-.*\.yang$/ && $3==0 {print}'
-rw------- john/users        0 2021-10-18 16:01 ./empty.yang
-rw------- john/users        0 2021-10-18 16:01 ./filename with spaces.yang
```

This is more than what we want, so let's print only the name part. We first measure the length of the 5 first fields, including the spaces, with the `match` function (that sets a variable named `RLENGTH`) and remove them with `substr`:

```sh
$ tar -tvf foo.tar | awk '/^-.*\.yang$/ && $3==0 {
    match($0,/(\S+\s+){4}\S+\s/); print substr($0,RLENGTH+1)}'
./empty.yang
./filename with spaces.yang
```

We could try to optimize a bit by calling `match` only on the first line but I am not 100% sure that all output lines are perfectly aligned, so let's call it on each line.

We are almost done: just pass this to `tar -f foo.tar --delete <filename>`, one name at a time. `xargs` can do this for us but there is a last trick: as file names can contain spaces we must use another separator, something that cannot be found in file names, like the `NUL` character (ASCII code 0). Fortunately GNU `awk` can use `NUL` as Output Record Separator (`ORS`) and `xargs` has the `-0` option to use it as input separator. So, let's put all this together:

```sh
$ tar -tvf foo.tar | awk -vORS=$"\0" '/^-.*\.yang$/ && $3==0 {
    match($0,/(\S+\s+){4}\S+\s/); print substr($0,RLENGTH+1)}' |
    xargs -0 -n1 tar -f foo.tar --delete
$ tar -tvf foo.tar
drwx------ john/users        0 2021-10-18 16:34 ./
-rw------- john/users        0 2021-10-18 16:34 ./nonyang
drwx------ john/users        0 2021-10-18 15:22 ./foo.yang/
-rw------- john/users        7 2021-10-18 15:22 ./nonempty.yang
```

Inside your `for` loop:

```sh
for f in *.tar.gz; do
    echo "Processing file $f"
    t="${f%.*}"
    gzip -cd "$f" > "$t"
    tar -tvf "$t" | awk -vORS=$"\0" '/^-.*\.yang$/ && $3==0 {
      match($0,/(\S+\s+){4}\S+\s/); print substr($0,RLENGTH+1)}' |
      xargs -0 -n1 tar -f "$t" --delete
    gzip -c9 "$t" > "$f.new"
    echo "******************************************"
done
```

Note that we must decompress the tarballs before editing them because GNU tar cannot edit compressed tarballs.

Comment: Thankyou so much sir for such a brief explanation.

for f in *.tar.gz; do
    echo "Processing file $f"
    d="$(mktemp -d)"
    tar -xf "$f" -C "$d"
    find "$d" -type f -name '*.yang' -size 0 -print -delete
    tar -C "$d" -czf "$f.new" .
    rm -rf "$d"
    echo "******************************************"
done

this code worked absolutely fine for me.
i would like to ask that as the new tar.gz file is creating as xyz.tar.gz.new so i want the same name for new file and previous file should be deleted.

So how can i do this?

Comment: Well, `rm` is a quite simple command. Try `man rm` to learn about it. Then modify the script to remove (`rm`) the old tarball after it has been unpacked and to repack a tarball without the `new` extension. Trying to solve yourself simple problems like this is the best way to learn.